# Jsoup parse specific attributes

Tags: android, parsing, jsoup

I'm newbie to Android development and to HTML Parsing. There's specific construction, e.g.

```
  <div class="submitted"> TEXT 1 <div class="class"> TEXT 2 </div></div>
```

I only need to extract **TEXT 1**.

Element a = doc.select("div[class]").get(x);  where x - integer, doesn't work as I need.
Moreover, I can't specify select("div[class="submitted"]).

How can I select only from "submitted" class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the [documentation](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax). You can select the class via `div.submitted`.

Comment: I see, but won't `div.submitted` select both Text 1 and Text 2 (Text 2 is in "submitted" class too, but it's also in another class)

Comment: Yes. What you do is `Elements divs = doc.select("div.submitted");`. This selelects all `div`s with class `submitted`. The result is a list of elements, hence, the return type is an object of `Elements`.